# MvvmCross bind command with parameter in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, binding, xamarin, mvvmcross

i am currently working on a simple app developped with Xamarin and MvvmCross.
I have a simple list of items and i want a click on an item open a new view.

I managed to do that in Android with :

this code in the .axml of the view

ListCustomersView.xaml

```
<MvxListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listcustomerscell"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ListCustomers; ItemClick ShowCommand"
        android:id="@+id/listCustomersView" />
```

and this code in the ViewModel file :

ListCustomersViewModel.cs

```
private MvxCommand<CustomerListDTO> _showCommand;
public ICommand ShowCommand
{
     get { return _showCommand ?? (_showCommand = new MvxCommand<CustomerListDTO>(c => this.ShowCustomerDetail(c))); }
}

public void ShowCustomerDetail(CustomerListDTO c)
{
    ShowViewModel<CustomerDetailViewModel>(new CustomerDetailParameters() { CustomerID = c.Id });
}
```

As you can see, i send a parameter through the command : an instance of the CustomerDetailParameters class. It works well in Android, but i do not manage to do that in Windows Phone.

I m using this code in the ListCustomersView.xaml :

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ListCustomers}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:ListCustomersCell />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

The ShowCommand is well called but the CustomerListDTO which should be sent is null. I imagine i am not using the good code. If you have any idea, i will take them.

Thanks for any help and have a good day !

Comment: You are not passing commandParameters when invoking command. try this
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listBox,Path=ItemsSource}

Comment: You do not need to send the parameter in the command back to your VM as this not the good practice. in your VM you have the instance of the Model. If you set Mode="TowWay" in your ItemSource binding than any change in the view will be sent VM

Comment: I I add the line CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listBox,Path=ItemsSource}, I got an InvalidCastException :
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[Domain.MainModule.DTOs.Customers.CustomerListDTO]' to type 'Domain.MainModule.DTOs.Customers.CustomerListDTO'.

I think the problem is ItemsSource is a collection while the command is looking for a CustomerListDTO

Comment: Well, it works now ! I replace Path=ItemsSource by Path=SelectedItem in the line you give me. Thanks you very much for your help Muhammad.

Comment: You can also use one of the many EventToCommand implementations to bind an ItemClick event to a command and pass along the args. Some relevant reading: http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/01/using-the-eventargsconverter-in-mvvm-light-and-why-is-there-no-eventtocommand-in-the-windows-8-1-version/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Command paramter is not passed to the command. Try below code by passing CommandParameter to the VM

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listBox, Path=SelectedItem}
```