# Navigating back to Panorama control issues

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, mvvmcross, panorama-control

I'm trying to develop a Windows Phone application with the MvvmCross framework.
I have a MainView which corresponds to a panorama control with ListBox as Item.

So my MainView contains the following XAML code :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <phone:Panorama Title="CustomerReference">

        <!--Élément un de panorama-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Projets" DataContext="{Binding ListProjectsVM}">
           <myviews:ListProjectsView />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>

        <!--Élément deux de panorama-->
        <phone:PanoramaItem Header="Clients" DataContext="{Binding ListCustomersVM}">
            <myviews:ListCustomersView />
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
    </phone:Panorama>
</Grid>
```

So as you can see, I have two Views in my panorama control. Each of this view contains a ListBox. In order to open the "detail" view corresponding of the row of my lists, I used the following code :

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ShowCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listBox,Path=SelectedItem}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When the user clicks on an item of the list, all work perfectly, but when the user comes back to my MainView and tries to switch to the second view of my panorama control, it opens the last "detail" view of the list which had been opened because it considers the user clicked on the ListBox. After coming back from this "detail" view, the MainView goes to the second view of the panorama control.

I you have any idea, i'll take it.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Weird. Can you please add the code for the view models as well? Also, did you try working with better suited event such as SelectionChanged? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303199/mvvmcross-bind-command-with-parameter-in-windows-phone

Comment: Hello eshaham. This is not a binding issue. It works well. The problem is graphic. I used SelectionChanged before but the user can't re-open a "detail" view after coming back from a "detail" view because the selection hadn't changed. And I can't set the SelectedIndex to -1 after my treatment beacuse I'm in a command in the ViewModel. I have no access to the View

Comment: You can alway bind the listbox's SelectedItem property to a SelectedItem property in the viewmodel - then you can reset it to null. But it doesn't seem to be the problem. Where is the ShowCommand defined? It could be that when you click an item on one list, the command on the second view model gets fired as well.

Comment: Bind the listbox's SelectedItem property to a SelectedItem property in the viewmodel and reset it to null after the treatment resolves my problem. It works perfectly. Thanks you for your help !